# unable to do type casting string to int in C# , giving error - Input string was not in a correct format

Tags: c#, int

I want to convert a string into int. I have string value like this `"45,454,566.00"`. While typecasting throwing error

> Input string was not in a correct format

```
int GrandTotalInWords = Int32.Parse(grandtotal);//error
grandTotalInWords.InnerHtml = ConvertNumbertoWords(GrandTotalInWords);
```

Comment: The number inside string is not of `int` type. You can do it in two steps; parse first as floating number (e.g. `double`) and then convert to int: `(int)double.Parse(grandTotal)`. This is assuming what current culture knows about thousands separator.

Comment: @Sinatr There is no guarantee that current culture settings of OP to parse this string to `double` either.

Comment: @SonerGönül, that's what I assume, maybe his current culture works for `double.Parse("45,454,566.00")` then he can either use `NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint` (which I didn't know until now) or parse as `double` and convert to `int` (that's how I would convert e.g. `"1.123"` to `int` myself).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all, `int.Parse` uses [`NumberStyles.Integer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberstyles) which does not includes *any* thousands and decimal separator styles.

As a second, your `CurrentCulture` *might* not use `,` as a  [`NumberGroupSeparator`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.numbergroupseparator) and/or might not use `.` as a [`NumberDecimalSeparator`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.numberdecimalseparator).

Just specify your culture settings and number styles;

```
int GrandTotalInWords = int.Parse(grandtotal, 
                        NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint | NumberStyles.AllowThousands, 
                        CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

By the way, if your fraction part is *not* always zero, that makes your `string` is not a valid format for an `int`. In such a case, you *might* need to parse it to a floating-point type like `double` as;

```
double GrandTotalInWords = double.Parse(grandtotal, 
                           NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint | NumberStyles.AllowThousands, 
                           CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: on a sidenote this works when the fraction part is 0. Using `int.Parse` will work for "1,232.00" but not for "1,232.50". It will give an overflow exception. That is because a number with fraction >0 can never be placed in an Int. In that case you need to use another type which supports the faction.

Comment: @Dbuggy Right. I added that option as well. Thanks.